# Android - write a test that opens camera and takes a picture

Tags: android

I wan't to make an integration test that opens camera and take a picture.
Is it possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by using internal intent for CAMERA. Here are a few links for startup:

[Android camera demo](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

[Camera example](https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example)

[Android Camera example](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-camera-example.html)